# cannot set cookies through chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to inject cookies in chrome through selenium.
I get the webdriver which opens the chrome, with my extension for injecting cookies.

My `background.js` code is :

```
chrome.cookies.set({
            "url": "http://fb.com/apps",
            "domain": ".fb.com",
            "expirationDate": 1422442443,
            "httpOnly": false,
            "name": "mbox",
            "path": "/apps",
            "value": "check#true#1422440643|session#1422440582628-397448#1422442443"
        }, function(state) {

            console.log("JSON.stringify(cookie) : " + JSON.stringify(state));

            console.log(" chrome.extension.lastError : " + chrome.extension.lastError);

            console.log(" chrome.runtime.lastError : " + chrome.runtime.lastError);

            if (!state || state == null) {
                console.log("cookies are not inserted " + chrome.runtime.lastError);
            }
```

But my console says this :

```
[39056:39064:0128/225156:INFO:CONSOLE(76)] "JSON.stringify(cookie) : undefined", source: chrome-extension://pmmbjehfpklkbfjpenkfelkpagmnhlld/background.js (76)
[39056:39064:0128/225156:INFO:CONSOLE(77)] " chrome.extension.lastError : undefined", source: chrome-extension://pmmbjehfpklkbfjpenkfelkpagmnhlld/background.js (77)
[39056:39064:0128/225156:INFO:CONSOLE(78)] " chrome.runtime.lastError : undefined", source: chrome-extension://pmmbjehfpklkbfjpenkfelkpagmnhlld/background.js (78)
[39056:39064:0128/225156:INFO:CONSOLE(80)] "cookies are not inserted undefined", source: chrome-extension://pmmbjehfpklkbfjpenkfelkpagmnhlld/background.js (80)
```

Also when the browser opens and I use the inspector to see the Resources -> Cookies. I can't see anything. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To use cookies APIs, did you request for permission in your extension manifest? Refer this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies

Comment: Is `".fb.com"` a valid value for `domain`?

Comment: i think i tried without that too @Xan what can i do ?

Comment: No idea. `chrome.runtime.lastError` should NOT be undefined in this case. This is actually a Chrome bug if it gives no failure information.

Comment: I hope the code how much  I have shown here is correct including the callback .?

Answer (score 0):

> expirationDate: The expiration date of the cookie as the number of
>   seconds since the UNIX epoch. If omitted, the cookie becomes a session
>   cookie.

While your expirationDate is '1422442443', it was Sat Jan 17 1970 19:07:22 GMT+0800, it means the cookie set correctly but expired. So, you cannot find your cookie and there is no error as well.

Solution: set with new Date().getTime() / 1000 + [ExpirationDate]